# Calculating an element's position within a <p>

Tags: css

Is it possible to calculate if an element is at the start of a new line within a `<p>`? For example take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

You'll see that the Twitter button has a slight margin to it. This is fine when it's following a word, but I was wondering if there was a hidden CSS gem that'd allow me to say "if you're the first 'thing' on a line then lose your margin-left".

Comment: Is this margin that you are adding yourself? I have tried reproducing your question [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYsQY/) and I am not seeing this `margin-left` problem.

Comment: Yep, the button has a 3px margin each side as a space doesn't give it enough space

Comment: post the html please where you have that button and p

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The answer was `p button:first-child` or `p > button`, but neither work. See the comments.

You might want to set the margin to 0 all the time and then make sure the button always has a space before it. (Edit: won't work either, since a space is not enough. Again, see the comments.)

Comment: Sorry, I gave you wrong information which is why I deleted my comment. `p + button` means a button that immediately follows a `p` tag. It would actually be `p button:first-child`

Comment: A space doesn't give it enough space, hence why I had to add a margin to it. Looks like JS may be the only way...

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Oops. `:first-child` won't do the trick either, because if will work only on elements! And since textnodes aren't elements, the button in `<p>text<button/>more text</p>` will also count as a first-child! I don't know what the answer is now.

Comment: I agree, it won't work as an answer for this, but it would be the way to target the button only if it was the first element.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this calculation programmatically using JavaScript, but I'm not aware of any CSS tricks that will do it for you.

The basic JavaScript algorithm for doing this is to append an invisible node to your document with the same text styling as your paragraphs of text.  Then you gradually add text to it, checking its width after each addition to see where the linebreaks are.  Then when you've worked out what the width of the final line is, you check to see if that width would put the twitter button on the next line by itself, and update the CSS styles appropriately to remove the margin.  This needs to be done for each `<p>` on the page that includes a twitter button.

It's not the most straightforward approach (in fact, Mr. Lister's solution is far simpler and produces a comparable effect as long as the margin is not more than a few pixels wide), but it's not quite as bad as it sounds, either.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fBUnW/6/

Comment: An interesting idea, I don't know if it needs to be that complex though. I was going to use jQuery's `position()` to retrive the `x` distance the button is from its parent's boundaries. If it equals its margin, then it'd lose its left margin (since it'll be on a new line and up to the left of the `<p>`).